# How to make another button appear when a first button is clicked and then allow it to disappear automatically when a second button is clicked?

Tags: android

I have a horizontal scroll with set of buttons at the top part of the screen. I want buttons to appear below when one of the buttons above are clicked.

Comment: put your code please

Comment: Have you tried anything? We are here to help if you have an error not write your code.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: use visibility property

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button1=new Button(context);
button1.setText("test");
button1.setId(id);
containerlayout.add(button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Must place your buttons on top as well as bottom and then need to set visibility on basis of your click event